# Use ternary operator in C#

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I am getting error while writing this line of code:

```cs
double h = model.WorkHours.Value>=0 ? model.WorkHours.Value : "";
```

I want to check if the value is equal and greater than `0` then get that value or else get blank or null.

Comment: `""` is empty string, which is type of `string` and not `double`(and have not implicit conversion to `double`).

Comment: @GuruStron, how to achieve it?

Comment: change it to correct `double` value which is valid in your case, `0` for example. Or use [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: I get the feeling that you don't like the `0` as default. Is this the reason why you tried to assign an empty string in the else condition?

Answer (score 9):

What happens when the condition is `false`?  This:

```
double h = "";
```

A `string` value can't be set to a `double`.  The default for a `double` would be a `0` instead:

```
double h = model.WorkHours.Value >= 0 ? model.WorkHours.Value : 0;
```

Or, as specifically as possible:

```
double h = model.WorkHours.Value >= 0 ? model.WorkHours.Value : 0.0d;
```

You could also rely on `default` if you like:

```
double h = model.WorkHours.Value >= 0 ? model.WorkHours.Value : default(double);
```

If you want the value to truly be *empty* then you might consider using a `double?` (shorthand for `Nullable<double>`):

```
double? h = model.WorkHours.Value >= 0 ? model.WorkHours.Value : new Nullable<double>();
```

Comment: Or `Math.Max(model.WorkHours.Value, 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Because a double doesnt have `null` or blank string as an allowable value, if you really want the default value to be a `null` or blank string, you will need to do one of the following.

Use an optional type along with an explicit type conversion:

```
double? h = model.WorkHours.Value >= 0 ? (double?) model.WorkHours.Value : null;
```

Use a string:

```
string h = model.WorkHours.Value >= 0 ? model.WorkHours.Value.ToString() : "";
```